# EntityFramework.Core adding to net4.6 and universal windows class libraries works, adding to portable class library targetting both doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nuget

I wish to add a reference to the EntityFramework.Core NuGet packet (currently at version 7.0.0-rc1-final) to a portable class library, targetting both .NET framework 4.6 and Windows Universal 10.0. However I'm getting the following output:

```
Restoring packages for 'ClassLibrary1'.
Restoring packages for C:\*snip*\project.json...
EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-rc1-final is not compatible with .NETPlatform,Version=v5.0.
Some packages are not compatible with .NETPlatform,Version=v5.0.
All packages are compatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.
All packages are compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
All packages are compatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6 (win-x86).
All packages are compatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6 (win-x64).
All packages are compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
All packages are compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
All packages are compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
All packages are compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
All packages are compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
All packages are compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Package restore failed for 'ClassLibrary1'.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ClassLibrary1'.
========== Finished ==========
```

I have no idea what this .Net v5.0 reference means and where it comes from. To make it even more strange, it is perfectly possible to add the EFcore packet to class libraries solely targeted to Universal windows or .Net framework v4.6:

[image: as shown, you can add the packet to individual libraries but not to a portable library]

As shown, you can add the packet to individual libraries but not to a portable library. Why is this?

Comment: Have you figured out the answer to this?

Comment: @BCA Sadly I have not

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982847/trying-to-install-ef-core-with-portable-class-library-targeting-net-4-6-1?stw=2