# Why can't EntityFramework.Core be added to a simple PCL?

Tags: portable-class-library, entity-framework-core

Am I missing something obvious?

1. Open Visual Studio 2015 Update 2
2. Add a new Portable Class Library project, targeting .NET 4.6 and UWP 10
3. Attempt to install NuGet package **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** v1.0.0-rc2-final

It fails with "EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-rc1-final is not compatible with .NETPlatform,Version=v5.0."

Is this *supposed* to work?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, here is my PCL properties:
[image]

Comment: Very strange... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installation with nuget unfortunately does not working out of the box. You have to modify the project.json by your self to get it working!

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html

"tools": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "imports": [
      "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
}

For more info :
[Trying to install EF Core with Portable Class Library targeting .Net 4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982847/trying-to-install-ef-core-with-portable-class-library-targeting-net-4-6-1?stw=2)

Comment: Thanks, but nothing I've tried from those discussions or your answer have worked. It sounds like a huge mess right now, so I'll revisit EF Core once MS has all this dependency & platform mess sorted out.

Comment: You have right it is a really mess now some of libaries are still .net 4.5 and other libraries core 1 and so on you have really to fight to get something work!